# $rootScope.$apply in jasmine test triggers http GET from module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a Jasmine unit test that is testing an Angular controller whereby a function returns a promise and populates a controller field with the results of the promise. I'm testing this to check that the field gets populated and calling $rootScope.$apply to resolve the promise and set the value.

When the $rootScope.$apply is called I get an error due to a module attempting to GET a json file in its config setup.

Karma shows the error t be related to $hhtpBackend and comes from angular-mocks.js

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /languages/en.json
No more request expected
       at $httpBackend (c:\dev\myapp\scrips\angular-mocks.js:1244:17)
       at sendReq (c:\dev\myapp\scripts\angular.js)
       at serverRequest (c:\dev\myapp\scripts\angular.js)
       at Scope.$eval
       at Scope.$digest
       at Scope.$apply
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Karma to expect a call. Something like the following should work:

```
      // Note this is just for a typical test
      it('should make an http get request',function() {
        httpBackend.expectGET(fullUrlToGoTo).respond({data: 'Success'});
        // function that triggers the call
        httpBackend.flush();
      });
```

But in your case because it's happening in the setup portion you'd need to move it into a `beforeEach` function and, I believe, ensure it's called before you load your app module.

Comment: Awesome that stopped the error I was seeing, thanks for that. My promise isn't resolving but I'll look into that now and figure that part out

Comment: @AnthonyJoanes No problem. Promises can be annoying. The correct way is to inject $q and call $q.defer(). Then you'll be-able to control what part of the promise comes back i.e. either resolve or reject

Comment: Thanks @Katana24. I got it all working now doing exactly that with $q service and mocking my service dependency. Thanks for the $httpBackend tip, I used chutzpah on my last project and didn't have to set things up in this way.